# In a text, how to tell the difference between a date (of the year) and days/months?

Tags: time

Seeing, for exampe, **4月から** (or まで）in a text, how to tell if it means 'since April' or '4 months ago'　（respectively, 'until April' or 'after 4 months) ?

Similarly, how to tell if **4日から**  (or まで） means 'since the 4th this month' or '4 days ago' （respectively, 'until the 4th this month' or 'after 4 days)?

Answer (score 4):

These will almost always mean "since April/the 4th" (I can't think of an example where they wouldn't).

> - From 4 months ago　→　[４ヶ月前]{よん・か・げつ・まえ}から
> - 4 months later　→　[４ヶ月後]{よん・か・げつ・ご}
> - Since April　→　[4月]{し・がつ}から
> - Until 4 months from now　→　[４ヶ月後]{よん・か・げつ・ご}まで

​

> - From 4 days ago　→　[４日前]{よっか・まえ}から
> - 4 days later　→　[４日後]{よっか・ご}
> - Since the 4th of the month　→　[4日]{よっか}から
> - Until 4 days from now　→　[4日後]{よっか・ご}まで

Answer (score 0):

- [４ヶ月前]{よん・か・げつ・まえ}から　⇔　From 4 months ago
- [４月]{し・がつ}から　⇔　 From April
- [４日前]{よっかまえ}から 　⇔　From 4 days ago
- [今月４日]{こんげつよっか}から　⇔　From the 4th of this month

Time interval for months is indicated by adding the character "ヶ” (pronounced ka) before 月.

*The small ke (ヶ) is a Japanese character, typographically a small form of the katakana character ケ ke.　While identical in shape to a small ケ, the shape is actually an abbreviation for the kanji 箇* [more at 
[Wikipedia, Small ke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_ke)
]

Etymology: 箇/個/个 is a counter used sometimes in Chinese coming ***before*** the object, but in Japanese is only used ***before*** the object for counting months, and in other cases where it is used,  it always comes **after**, e.g.,

- Japanese [４ヶ月]{よん・か・げつ}, c.f. ４个月 (Simplified Ch.), ４個月 (Traditional Ch.)

  - unique instance where Japanese borrows Chinese pre position 個 counter regular expression:
  - **{number}{counter(noun)}{noun}**
- Japanese [一人]{ひとり}, c.f. 一個人 (Traditional Ch.) or 一个人 (Simplified Ch.) -

  - unique case (including [一人前]{いち・にん・まえ}) of native Japanese post position counter regular expression:
  - **{number}{counter(noun)}**
- Japanese [一日間]{いち・にち・かん}, c.f. 一天 (Traditional+Simplified Ch. - no counter!)

  - usual case of native Japanese post position counter regular expression:
  - **{noun}{number}{counter(noun)}**

*Note: I don't have a reference to show that the first two cases above described as "unique" are actually unique.  If someone knows a reference or a counter example, please post.*

Comment: 「4月から」は「よんがつから」でなく「しがつから」と読むほうが普通だと思います。「4日間前から」は「４日前から」「よっかまえから」のほうがいいと思います。「今月4日から」は「こんげつよんにちから」より「こんげつよっかから」と読む（または「今月の４日から」「こんげつのよっかから」）ほうが普通だと思います。

Comment: `case where Japanese doesn't use a counter` I would say that 人【り・にん】 is the counter, but I guess you can analyze it differently.

Comment: @Earthliŋ - I did analyze it differently, as a special case of the borrowed Chinese counting form {number}{counter(type)}{type} where {counter(type)} is NULL.  However, because the etymology of 一人 is not Chinese, that analysis is not historically appropriate.  I will change it.